# What causes the OWA 2013 login loop?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, login, outlook-web-access, exchange-2013

When attempting to login to OWA with valid credentials, the login screen reappears without any form or sort of error message. Despite this the logon procedure has succeeded, because when I re-enter the OWA URL my mailbox is opened.

I am unsure as to the cause of this problem. The strange thing is that it does not happen all the time. Exchange is installed on the domain controller, but other than that I can't think of any possible causes.

Could it be a misconfiguration somewhere? Perhaps something to do with the IIS or DNS configuration?

Comment: Try clearing browser caches. Also try a different browser and see if the symptoms persist.

Comment: I have seen it happen on almost every browser, from Internet Explorer to Firefox and Chrome. Also, clearing the browser caches seems to have no effect.

Comment: Are you able to get any logs from IIS (they are in %windir%\system32\logfiles\ I would recommend stopping IIS services renaming the latest file, start services and recreate the problem to limited the amount of data in the log file.

Answer (score 1):

I've been digging through this for serveral hours. It was for a certificate. Uninstall your current certificate (Get-ExchangeCertificate/Remove-ExchangeCertificate) and resetiis.

Comment: The OP makes no mention of a certificate error. Could you go into a bit more detail on the process?

Answer (score 1):

Old thread, but I had exactly the same issue and the problem was certificates.
I was using an ad-enrolled web server certificate from an internal ca.

As it turns out I had to use a Windows Server 2003 Enterprise (100.4) certificate instead of a Windows Server 2008 (100.3) certificate.